# How to use access_token (of Facebook Graph API)?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get FB user's full name using the access_token. I have the access_token with me but I am not sure how I can use it to access user information.

I have read the documentation and it says to get more user info we can use:
https://graph.facebook.com/userid?access_token=...

So, does this mean I need to use cURL to get response from this URL?

Btw, I am using PHP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accesstoken you can use for getting the information of the user which is necessary. Also if you have asked offline_access permission from user, you can store this accesstoken in your database and can get the user information even if he not logged in with facebook. That means, from next time you automtically get the information using this token.

Comment: To get another user's Full name using their user id, we can use the access_token in the same way. Right?